# How to prove the convergence of the series of variances in the theorem to prove strong law of large numbers

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

How to prove the convergence of the series of variances theorem in this case?

Let $ \{X_n\}_{n\ge1} $ be a sequence of independent random variables with $ \mathbf{E}X_n = 0 $ for all $ n\ge1 $ and let for some $ p \ge 1 $
\begin{equation}
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mathbf{E}|X_n|^{2p}}{n^{p+1}} < \infty.
\end{equation}
Prove that $ \frac{S_n}{n} \to 0 $ almost surely as $ n \to \infty $.

I use the next $ \textbf{Theorem} $ with $ b_n = n $ :

Let $ \{X_n\}_{n\ge1} $ be a sequence of independent random variables and let for some $ \varepsilon > 0 $ next conditions hold:
\begin{equation}
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbf{P}(|X_n| \ge \varepsilon b_n) < \infty,
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{b_n}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} \mathbf{E}Y_j \to 0 \quad \text{as}\quad n \to \infty , \quad Y_j = X_j \mathbf{I}\{ X_j \le \varepsilon b_j \},
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mathbf{Var}Y_n}{b_n^2} < \infty.
\end{equation}
Then $ \frac{S_n}{b_n}\to 0 $ a.s.

I proof the first and the second conditions using exercise's condition. But I can't prove the third. I tried to estimate variance by this way:
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{Var}Y_n \le \mathbf{E}[X_n^2; \; |X_n| \le n] = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\mathbf{E}[X_n^2; \; k < |X_n| \le k+1] \le \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k^{2p-2}}\mathbf{E}[X_n^{2p}; \; k < |X_n| \le k+1]
\end{equation}
But nothing worked.

Comment: What does the $D$ in $DY_n$ stand for?

Comment: D is the notation for variance

Comment: This strategy can't really work - take $X_n = \pm \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\log^{1/2q}(n)},$ $q \ge 1$. Then the hypothesis is satisfied for every $p > q$, but, for large enough $n,$ $\mathrm{Var}[Y_n]/n^2 = 1/n \log^{1/q} n$ which is not summable.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4336993/proving-frac1n-sum-k-1nx-k-to-0-a-s